# Replace Text in a textfield with Image

Tags: forms, image, text, replace, emoji

I have a form on my website.
Inside this form a some emoji buttons.

If a user clicks one of this buttons they add an emoji to a `<textfield>`,
but they look like this " :) ".

So how can i replace the :) Emoji with images.

Example: If a user click a button it should add `<img src="img/emoji/1.png">` and display it.

Comment: You can use jquery selector to select :) and replace with Image element. If you are not using jquery then same can be done by plain js.

Comment: Presumably your form is powered by some editor library, do you know which one? What is your website running on?

Answer (score 0):

Use the UTF8 characters for the emoji's.  Since the UTF8 emoji's are considered text characters, you don't need to use any HTML for this, and they will render in normal textarea's and text input's without anything special.

Here's a reference for some unicode UTF8 emoji's.  In your buttons code, replace the ;) or whatever with the code for the UTF8 symbol-- for example on the table in the link it shows the code U+1F600 for a smiley face.  In your script you want to say it as `\u1F600` in quotes.  This will render the emoji character.  Most browsers, especially on mobile, have good support for these characters, but you can bolster that by importing an emoji font using css.

http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Addendum:  You can even cut and paste UTF8 emoji's directly into your code.  Since they are valid characters in UTF8, they are valid code.. you could even use them in variable names

Comment: The proplem is that i dont want the UTF8 Emojis. I want to use the Twitch emotes

Comment: @RyuZockt "Emote and badge images are property of Twitch Interactive or their respective owners. Do not reuse without obtaining their permission."

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might look for a Twitch font, or one that is similar.  There may be one that is open-source licensed.   It might not be identical, but then you would not have to worry about copyright violation and the adjustments to your script would be minimal.